# Confidence interval for variables with multiple categories - estimation of difference

Tags: confidence-interval, categorical-data, binary-data, minitab

I have performed a chi-squared test on two categorical variables - one is a dichotomous variable (eg survived, died), whereas the other has multiple sub-categories (location A, location B, location C and so on).

I want to present a confidence interval for the estimation of difference between the categories but I don't know how to do this for such data. I'm using Minitab and when I try to get a CI it tells me 'there must be exactly two distinct subscripts'.

My data is similar to this:
| Place | Survived | Died |
|-------|----------|------|
|A|300|200|
|B|234|536|
|C|62|463|
|D|364|34|

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please give us more detail on what exactly you want a CI on? You say "difference between the categories", do you mean you want to know what the difference is between the average proportion of people that survive and the average prop that died, where "average" means averaging over A,B,C,D or something else?

Comment: Ah, maybe you're hoping a (n interpretable) CI naturally accompanies the p-value your Chi2 test gave you? Unfortunately, this is not the case.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I'm looking for an estimation of difference of means between those who survived and those who didn't.